# How to jest test lightning-pills in LWC

Tags: javascript, jestjs, lwc

It's the first time I'm using jest tests and I'm trying to test a method that generates lightning pills from a query of groups with access permissions (array). The lightning pills get updated whenever a new group is either added or removed from an array.

I need to test the following scenarios, but I'm not sure if I created the tests correctly:

(these are already properly functioning in actual code).

Test#1: The returned array from query should be displayed as lightning pills

Test#2: Clicking the X icon in a pill should remove the selected pill from array

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/af27A.png)

For Test#1, the jest test fails for a mock array of multiple or single elements. I'm not sure where is the problem, but debugging shows this line is undefined:

```js
  const detailEls = element.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('lightning-pill');
```

I'm using return method GroupController.getSpecificGroups:

public with sharing class GroupController {

```
/* Description: Gets the groups where the contact is being shared to
*
*/
@AuraEnabled
public static List<sObject> getSpecificGroups(String recordId){
    List<GroupShare> groupShareList = new List<GroupShare>();
    List<sObject> returnShareList = new List<sObject>();

    try{
        groupShareList = [SELECT Id, UserOrGroupId, UserOrGroup.Name, ContactId, Contact.Name,
                            FROM GroupShare 
                            WHERE ContactId =: recordId];

        if(groupShareList != NULL && !groupShareList.isEmpty()){
            for(GroupShare csBuff : groupShareList){
                returnShareList.add(csBuff);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(queryException qExcp){
    }
    return returnShareList;
}
```

}

Jest test is passed when testing if the method successfully passes recordId to the apex method call so I'm thinking there's no problem with method calls.

```js
   it('passes the recordId to the Apex method correctly', () => {
        const RECORD_ID = '00AAABBBCCCDDD12345';
        const APEX_PARAMETERS = { recordId: RECORD_ID };

        // Assign mock value for resolved Apex promise
        getSpecificGroups.mockResolvedValue(APEX_GROUPS_SUCCESS);

        // Create initial element
        const element = createElement('c-cmm-specific-group-sharing', {
            is: Cmm_specificGroupSharing
        });
        element.recordId = RECORD_ID;
        document.body.appendChild(element);

        // Select button for executing Apex call
        const buttonEl = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('lightning-button');
        buttonEl.click();

        return flushPromises().then(() => {
            // Validate parameters of mocked Apex call
            expect(getSpecificGroups.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual(APEX_PARAMETERS);
        });
    });
```

For Test#2, jest test for removing pills fail. The pill is not removed from array using dispatchEvent:

```js
it('handleRemoveSelectedItem works', () => {
        // Create element
        const element = createElement('c-cmm-specific-group-sharing', {
            is: Cmm_specificGroupSharing
        });
        element.availableGroups = APEX_GROUPS_SUCCESS;
        document.body.appendChild(element);
    
        // Remove a selected item
        const selPills = element.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('lightning-pill');
        selPills[0].dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('remove'));
        // Check selection
        expect(element.availableGroups.length).toBe(0);
    });
```

**Jest Test**

```js
import { createElement } from 'lwc';
import Cmm_specificGroupSharing from 'c/c-cmm-specific-group-sharing';
import getSpecificGroups from '@salesforce/apex/GroupController.getSpecificGroups';
import delete from "@salesforce/apex/GroupController.delete";

// Mocking  Apex method call
jest.mock(
    '@salesforce/apex/GroupController.getSpecificGroups',
    () => {
        return {
            default: jest.fn()
        };
    },
    { virtual: true }
);

// Sample data for Apex call
const APEX_GROUPS_SUCCESS = [
    {
        "Id": "000001112222DDDD001",
        "UserOrGroupId":  "00AAABBBCCCDDD12345", 
        "Name":  "Asia Pacific"
    }
];

describe('c-cmm-specific-group-sharing', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        // The jsdom instance is shared across test cases in a single file so reset the DOM
        while (document.body.firstChild) {
            document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
        }
        // Prevent data saved on mocks from leaking between tests
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    // Helper function to wait until the microtask queue is empty. This is needed for promise
    // timing when calling imperative Apex.
    function flushPromises() {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        return new Promise(resolve => setImmediate(resolve));
    }

   it('passes the recordId to the Apex method correctly', () => {
        const RECORD_ID = '00AAABBBCCCDDD12345';
        const APEX_PARAMETERS = { recordId: RECORD_ID };

        // Assign mock value for resolved Apex promise
        getSpecificGroups.mockResolvedValue(APEX_GROUPS_SUCCESS);

        // Create initial element
        const element = createElement('c-cmm-specific-group-sharing', {
            is: Cmm_specificGroupSharing
        });
        element.recordId = RECORD_ID;
        document.body.appendChild(element);

        // Select button for executing Apex call
        const buttonEl = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('lightning-button');
        buttonEl.click();

        return flushPromises().then(() => {
            // Validate parameters of mocked Apex call
            expect(getSpecificGroups.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual(APEX_PARAMETERS);
        });
    });

    it('renders one sharing group', () => {
    
        // Assign mock value for resolved Apex promise
        getSpecificGroups.mockResolvedValue(APEX_GROUPS_SUCCESS);

        // Create initial element
        const element = createElement('c-cmm-specific-group-sharing', {
            is: Cmm_specificGroupSharing
        });
        document.body.appendChild(element);

     
        // Select button for executing Apex call
        const buttonEl = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('lightning-button');
        buttonEl.click();

        return flushPromises().then(() => {
      
            const detailEls = element.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('lightning-pill');
            expect(detailEls.length).toBe(APEX_GROUPS_SUCCESS.length);
            expect(detailEls[0].label).toBe(
                APEX_GROUPS_SUCCESS[0].Name
            );
        });
    });

    it('handleRemoveSelectedItem works', () => {
        // Create element
        const element = createElement('c-cmm-specific-group-sharing', {
            is: Cmm_specificGroupSharing
        });
        element.availableGroups = APEX_GROUPS_SUCCESS;
        document.body.appendChild(element);
    
        // Remove a selected item
        const selPills = element.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('lightning-pill');
        selPills[0].dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('remove'));
        // Check selection
        expect(element.availableGroups.length).toBe(0);
    });
});
```

**JS and HTML**

```js
import {
    LightningElement
    api
} from 'lwc';

import getSpecificGroups from '@salesforce/apex/GroupController.getSpecificGroups';
import deleteGroup from "@salesforce/apex/GroupController.deleteGroup";
 
export default class Cmm_specificGroupSharing extends LightningElement {

@api availableGroups;
    
@api
get recordId() {
    return this._recordId;
}
set recordId(value) {
    this._recordId = value;
}
connectedCallback() {
      this.getSpecificGroups();
  } 

getSpecificGroups() {
        this.availableGroups =[];
        getSpecificGroups({
                recordId: this._recordId,
            })
            .then(result => {
                result.map(gShare => {
                     let obj = {
                            'Id': gShare.Id,
                            'UserOrGroupId': gShare.UserOrGroupId,
                            'Name': gShare.UserOrGroup.Name
                        };  
                        this.availableGroups.push(obj);
                    return null;
                   
                })
                console.log('result' + JSON.stringify(result));
            })
            .catch((err) => {
            });
    }

handleRemoveSelectedItem(event) {
        const recordId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
        this.availableGroups = this. availableGroups.filter(item => item.id !== recordId);

        deleteGroup ({
            recordId: recordId
        })
        .then(() => {
            this.notifyUser('', this.deleteSuccessMsg, 'success');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            this.error = err;
        });
    }

}
```

```html
<template>
  <template for:each={availableGroups} for:item="groupShare">
      <lightning-pill
          data-id={groupShare.Id}
          key={groupShare.Id}
          label={groupShare.Name}
          onremove={handleRemoveSelectedItem}>
      </lightning-pill>
  </template> 
</template>
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please, could you please try in this way?:

```
it('handleRemoveSelectedItem works', () => {
    // Create element
    const element = createElement('c-cmm-specific-group-sharing', {
        is: Cmm_specificGroupSharing
    });
    element.availableGroups = APEX_GROUPS_SUCCESS;
    document.body.appendChild(element);

    return Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
         // Remove a selected item
        let selPills = element.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('lightning-pill');
        selPills[0].dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('remove'));
    }) // Move foward
    .then(() => {
        selPills = element.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('lightning-pill');
        expect(selPills.length).toBe(0);
    });
});
```